# How do I prevent Main from being auto-generated in app.g.cs?

Tags: wpf, program-entry-point, app.xaml

I have a WPF project targeting .NET 5 and built with Visual Studio 2019.  I declared a custom `Main()` entry point, and have set the project "Startup object" property to target it.  To ensure a Main is not auto-generated, I removed App.xaml/.cs from the project, and re-added it as a Page component, as many have recommended.  I can step through the code and see that the correct `Main()` is being called.

However, after I added a constructor parameter to the `App` class I get a compiler error in App.g.cs:

```
CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter...
```

because it uses the default constructor.  Of course it will fail, but why is it still generating a `Main(`) in the first place, and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare an empty constructor as private like this :

```
private class_name(){}
```

And declare your desired constructor as public :

```
public class_name(params....){}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using that work around, but is there a way to stop the generation of Main entirely?